# En C# windows forms imprimir en lenguaje ZPL

Tags: c#, zpl

En C# necesito imprimir unos caracteres en lenguaje zpl, pero al hacer la ejecución la impresora no me toma el lenguaje e imprime solo los caracteres sin tomar en cuenta el lenguaje zpl.

Este es el código:

```csharp
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Drawing.Printing;

using System.IO;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ZPLBytes

{

    public class RawPrinterHelper

    {

        // Structure and API declarions:

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]

    public class DOCINFOA

    {

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;

    }

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

 

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="ClosePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

 

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter( IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level,  [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

 

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndDocPrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

 

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="StartPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

 

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="EndPagePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

 

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="WritePrinter", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten );

 

    // SendBytesToPrinter()

    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array

    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.

    // Returns true on success, false on failure.

    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter( string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)

    {

        Int32    dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;

        IntPtr    hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);

        DOCINFOA    di = new DOCINFOA();

        bool    bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

 

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";

        di.pDataType = "RAW";

 

        // Open the printer.

        if( OpenPrinter( szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero ) )

        {

            // Start a document.

            if( StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) )

            {

                // Start a page.

                if( StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) )

                {

                    // Write your bytes.

                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);

                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);

                }

                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);

            }

            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);

        }

        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information

        // about why not.

        if( bSuccess == false )

        {

                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        }

        return bSuccess;

    }

 

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szFileName )

    {

        // Open the file.

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);

        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.

        Byte []bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];

        bool bSuccess = false;

        // Your unmanaged pointer.

        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);

        int nLength;

 

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);

        // Read the contents of the file into the array.

        bytes = br.ReadBytes( nLength );

        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.

        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);

        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.

        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);

        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.

        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);

        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);

        return bSuccess;

    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter( string szPrinterName, string szString )

    {

        IntPtr pBytes;

        Int32 dwCount;

        // How many characters are in the string?

        dwCount = szString.Length;

        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert

        // the string to ANSI text.

        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);

        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.

        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);

        return true;

    }
    }
}
```

El código que se envía a la impresora

```csharp
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ZPLBytes

{

    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {

        public Form1()

        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            string s = "^XA^LH30,30\n^FO20,10^ADN,90,50^AD^FDHello World^FS\n^XZ\n";

            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

            pd.PrinterSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();

            if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
            {

                RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, s);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tras ejecutar el programa y hacer click en el botón de imprimir se imprime lo siguiente:

```
^XA^LH30,30
^FO20,10^ADN,90,50^AD^FDHello World^FS
^XZ
```

Entonces ¿alguien me puede explicar qué falta para que al imprimir tome el lenguaje zpl?
¿Me faltarán unas librerías?
He buscado otras respuestas y tratado con [los](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvWG9_rE9rg&pp=ugMICgJlcxABGAE%3D) [siguientes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044676/net-code-to-send-zpl-to-zebra-printers) y no consigo hacer que funcione.

Comment: tengo entendido que las impresoras esperan un archivo xml y ahi declararias todas tus variables y parametros de impresion.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el driver genérico "Generic / Text Only".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!